# How to provide automated user input in wlst

Tags: python, jython, wlst

How to provide automated user input in wlst? I am trying expectj, but i am getting few errors while spawning process in java code. The spawned process is a wlst script .py.

Is there any other simpler way to provide user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we have other options in Pythonic way, that is input() or raw_input() statement will give you the input option to read 
`wls:/offline> x=raw_input('Enter a number:')`
 or ELSE
you can try with command line arguments with [getopt](http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.in/2010/08/get-options-for-command-line-in-wlst.html)

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt( sys.argv[1:], "t:i", ["Timeout","Interval"] )
except getopt.GetoptError, err:
    print str(err)
```

Confirm did this worked for you?

Comment: python normal `input()` is not working in wlst py code, thanks `var=raw_input()` worked great!

Comment: @KarthikKumar, This could be due to WLST implementation with the old Python libraries. If it would have been added Python3 libs the story would be in different level!

Comment: right, its old Python 2.x